# How to get all noun phrases in Spacy

Tags: python, nlp, spacy

I am new to `Spacy` and I would like to extract "all" the noun phrases from a sentence. I'm wondering how I can do it. I have the following code:

```
import spacy

nlp = spacy.load("en")

file = open("E:/test.txt", "r")
doc = nlp(file.read())
for np in doc.noun_chunks:
    print(np.text)
```

But it returns only the base noun phrases, that is, phrases which don't have any other `NP` in them. That is, for the following phrase, I get the result below:

Phrase: `We try to explicitly describe the geometry of the edges of the images.`

Result: `We, the geometry, the edges, the images`.

Expected result: `We, the geometry, the edges, the images, the geometry of the edges of the images, the edges of the images.`

How can I get all the noun phrases, including nested phrases?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Please see commented code below to recursively combine the nouns. Code inspired by the [Spacy Docs here](https://spacy.io/usage/linguistic-features#navigating-around)

```
import spacy

nlp = spacy.load("en")

doc = nlp("We try to explicitly describe the geometry of the edges of the images.")

for np in doc.noun_chunks: # use np instead of np.text
    print(np)

print()

# code to recursively combine nouns
# 'We' is actually a pronoun but included in your question
# hence the token.pos_ == "PRON" part in the last if statement
# suggest you extract PRON separately like the noun-chunks above

index = 0
nounIndices = []
for token in doc:
    # print(token.text, token.pos_, token.dep_, token.head.text)
    if token.pos_ == 'NOUN':
        nounIndices.append(index)
    index = index + 1


print(nounIndices)
for idxValue in nounIndices:
    doc = nlp("We try to explicitly describe the geometry of the edges of the images.")
    span = doc[doc[idxValue].left_edge.i : doc[idxValue].right_edge.i+1]
    span.merge()

    for token in doc:
        if token.dep_ == 'dobj' or token.dep_ == 'pobj' or token.pos_ == "PRON":
            print(token.text)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But the output of your code is "[0, 5, 8]
We
geometry
edges
images
We
geometry
edges
images
We
geometry
edges
images"
What is it supposed to show?

Comment: I am getting the following from the code above. Are you running both loops? Which version of Spacy are you using? ----- We
the geometry
the edges
the images

[6, 9, 12]
We
the geometry of the edges of the images
We
geometry
the edges of the images
We
geometry
edges
the images

Comment: I have copied your code exactly. I'm suing spacy 2.0.8 with Python verison 3.6.4 on Widnows OS.

Comment: Strange - I am running this on linux but that should not result in different output. Can you try upgrading the language model to the latest version (https://spacy.io/models/en#en_core_web_sm) from Spacy also? The indices you are getting [0,5,8] vs what I get [6,9,12] indicate a difference in the parse tree. Are you running the code from the very first line? The first output should not be "[0,5,8] ...."

Comment: nice solution but I do not understand why you need the line `span = doc[doc[idxValue].left_edge.i : doc[idxValue].right_edge.i+1]`. Could you please explain? thanks!

Answer (score 3):

For every noun chunk you can also get the subtree beneath it.
Spacy provides two ways to access that:`left_edge` and `right edge` attributes and
the `subtree` attribute, which returns a `Token` iterator rather than a span.
Combining `noun_chunks` and their subtree lead to some duplication which can be removed later.

Here is an example using the `left_edge` and `right edge` attributes

```
{np.text
  for nc in doc.noun_chunks
  for np in [
    nc, 
    doc[
      nc.root.left_edge.i
      :nc.root.right_edge.i+1]]}                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 

==>

{'We',
 'the edges',
 'the edges of the images',
 'the geometry',
 'the geometry of the edges of the images',
 'the images'}
```

Answer (score 2):

Please try this to get all nouns from a text:

```
import spacy
nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")
text = ("We try to explicitly describe the geometry of the edges of the images.")
doc = nlp(text)
print([chunk.text for chunk in doc.noun_chunks])
```

Answer (score 2):

```
from spacy.matcher import Matcher
import spacy
nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")

doc = nlp('Features of the iphone applications include a beautiful design, smart search, automatic labels and optional voice responses.') ## sample text
matcher = Matcher(nlp.vocab)
pattern = [{"POS": "NOUN", "OP": "*"}] ## getting all nouns
matcher.add("NOUN_PATTERN", [pattern])
print(matcher(doc, as_spans=True))
```

Getting all the nouns of your text. Using matcher and patterns are great to get the combination you want. Change the `"en_core_web_sm"` if you want a better model `"en_core_web_bm"`